# Trying to execute HTML after PHP code

Tags: php, html

I am making a website where you can log in using HTTP Basic Authentication. Once a person logs in with the correct credentials, it will start a new session and have a link to continue to the another page. On the other page I want it to check to see if a session has been started by getting the username session variable that I created on the last page. If the session variable exists, I want it to execute the pages HTML code. If the session variable does not exist, It should give the user a link to the login page. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

```
// Second page checking to see if the session variables exists code
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 // Command to execute rest of webpage after PHP closing tag
} else {
    die("<a href='index.php'>Login</a>");
}
?>

<!-- HTML CODE THAT NEEDS TO BE EXECUTED -->
<p>Hi!</p>
```

Comment: What's your question/issue/problem?

Comment: Err … so you want it to continue? i.e. you want it to "not die"? So instead of saying `die()` you just *don't say `die()`*? Like the code you have does alraedy? I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: die - does well, as it suggests, die. Whole document process dies. Nothing comes after a die. Never use die. Use return, or just echo the a link

Comment: Seems like a lot of upvotes for a vague question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try and wrap your webpage content around an `if` in PHP tags.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        ?>
            <p>Hi!</p>
        <?php
    } else {
        die("<a href='index.php'>Login</a>");
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

After some consideration, `die` would be unneeded. You can just do the same for the if. This would return the result, and would also execute additional PHP code in the file if needed.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        ?>
            <p>Hi!</p>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
            <a href='index.php'>Login</a>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 // Command to execute rest of webpage after 

 ?>

<p>Hi!</p>

<?php

} else {
    die("<a href='index.php'>Login</a>");
}

?>
```

You need to move your conditional HTML into the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

well, i suggest :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
} 
else 
{
    echo "<a href='index.php'>Login</a>";
}
?>
<p>Hi!</p>
```

[Die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) will terminates execution of the script